# How to perform a simple backtest in python

Tags: python, back-testing

I'd like to know if there's a library where I can add lists of long, short, take profit, stop lose prices. then it calculates

-Net profit
-Drawdowns
-Long and short positions percentages
-Number of consecutive win and loss trades and their percentages

then plot a graph with those calculations